# jquery in 3rd party tool not integrating

Tags: jquery

I am trying to follow [this](http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1238). This produces in my case this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:rdXslExtension="urn:rdXslExtension">
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>LogiPoc</TITLE>
      <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rdTemplate/rdTheme/ProfessionalBlue/Theme.css" />
      <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rdTemplate/rdRoundCorners.css" />
      <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_SupportFiles/jqueryUI.css" />
      <SCRIPT src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></SCRIPT><SCRIPT src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT><SCRIPT src="_SupportFiles/Test.js"></SCRIPT>
      <META name="lgxver" content="11.4.46.313" />
      <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="rdTemplate/rdYui/global.js"></SCRIPT><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" src="rdTemplate/rdYui/yui-preload-min.js"></SCRIPT><SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">function rdBodyLoad() {document.body.appendChild(YUI.Env.cssStampEl);
         }
      </SCRIPT><SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">function rdValidateForm() {}</SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY onload="rdBodyLoad()">
      <FORM NAME="rdForm" method="POST">
         <SPAN id="rdReportHeader"></SPAN><SPAN id="rdReportHeader-end"></SPAN>
         <div id="rdMainBodyStart"></div>
         <div id="rdMainBody">
            <BR />
            <DIV id="divDatePicker"></DIV>
            <SPAN id="div1"></SPAN>
         </div>
         <div id="rdMainBodyEnd"></div>
         <SPAN id="rdReportFooter"></SPAN><SPAN id="rdReportFooter-end"></SPAN>
         <rdHidden></rdHidden>
      </FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The Test.js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divDatePicker").datepicker();
 });
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I presume the reason is that the div with id divDatePicker is nested. Is this correct? Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: You need to include `jquery.js` *before* `jqueryui.js`

Comment: Nice thanks. Have not touched jquery etc. for a while. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `jquery.js` in your page before `jqueryui.js`:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="_SupportFiles/Test.js"></script>   

    <!-- other scripts... -->
</head>
```